# MySQL query counting rows for unique column

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to create a very complex MySQL query that will result in the number of unique id where a single value shows up 3 times.

```
-- id ------ p -------- v -----
|  1   |     a     |    0     |
-------------------------------
|  1   |     a     |    0     |
-------------------------------
|  1   |     a     |    0     |
-------------------------------
|  1   |     b     |    15    |
-------------------------------
|  1   |     b     |    30    |
-------------------------------
|  2   |     a     |    0     |
-------------------------------
|  2   |     a     |    0     |
-------------------------------
|  2   |     a     |    0     |
-------------------------------
|  2   |     a     |    0     |
-------------------------------
|  2   |     b     |    85    |
-------------------------------
|  3   |     a     |    0     |
-------------------------------
|  3   |     a     |    0     |
-------------------------------
|  3   |     a     |    0     |
-------------------------------
|  3   |     b     |    51    |
-------------------------------
|  3   |     b     |    75    |
-------------------------------
```

For the id of `1` the value `a` for `column p` shows up 3 times. So we add one to the return value (Return value = 1), for id `3` the same thing occurs, where `a` shows up 3 times. So the return value should now be 2.

Essentially, I want to know how many `id`s in which the value `a` appears exactly `3` times and the `v` column equals `0`

Comment: where to show the new values?

Comment: any query you have tried before?

Answer (score 0):

```
select t.id
from mytable t
where t.p = 'a' and t.v = 0
group by t.id
having count(*) = 3
```

Comment: Does it return anything without last two lines (try to comment `group by` and `having` clauses)?

Comment: It returns multiple rows

Comment: OK, now try this: `select t.id, count(*) from mytable t where t.p = 'a' and t.v = 0 group by t.id order by 2 desc`

Comment: Hi, Ivan. This is not a valid answer. Please add explaination and read “[How do I write a good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)”